# How to parse vector XML from SdCard on Android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-vectordrawable

I have not found an assertive response in other threads of Stackoverflow.

There are many methods to par an xml from sdcard but I receive the same error. I don't understand why this is happening.

1) This is the method I'm using:

```
public XmlPullParser xmlVectorFromResource() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        try {
            String data;
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            File file = new 

            // testing loading a .xml from DCMI
            File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "/cityscape.xml");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);

            char[] InputBuffer = new char[fis.available()];
            isr.read(InputBuffer);
            data = new String(InputBuffer);
            isr.close();
            fis.close();
            XmlPullParser xpp = null;
            xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            xpp.setInput(new StringReader(data));
            return xpp;
        } catch (XmlPullParserException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

2) This is the vector I am trying. It is a valid one (I tested from res/drawables):
http://beetxt.com/N4c

3) This is how I am callind the method:

```
XmlPullParser drawable = null;
try {
    drawable = xmlVectorFromResource();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (drawable != null) {
    try {
        mImageview.setImageDrawable(VectorDrawableCompat
          .createFromXml(holder.cardView.getResources()
                , drawable));
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "Wapawm, problems");
}
```

4) And this is the error I'm receiving:
http://www.beetxt.com/ape/

I hope there is a solution.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Now I restart aplication and receiving a new error. LOL

This is what I'm receiving: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.util.XmlPullAttributes cannot be cast to android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser

Here is a test project where you can see the error github.com/denebchorny/vectorxmltest/tree/master

Comment: what does the error message look like?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author Sorry for the delay. I posted the error here: http://www.beetxt.com/ape/ but in essence is W/System.err: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: No start tag found. I am using a valid vector. I tested. What could be?.

Comment: I need to load a vector this way because I'm trying to load it from sdcard and checking path by path to find and compare a particular TAG.

Comment: @vtd-xml-author sir, now I'm receiving this error: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.util.XmlPullAttributes cannot be cast to android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser. Let me update the thread by adding a project test

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to load xml from SDcard using the call createFromXml. This call works on the XML files in res or drawable folder. The reason for it not working is that when we create apk the vector XML is converted into a binary format get and createFromXml understand that changed binary format.

If you want to load a vector from SDCard, one solution could be to create a PDF having this vector file.Put that PDF on SDCard and open it using PDFRenderer class to render the page in a bitmap. This way you can get the scaled bitmap of required size. But this will work only after API 21 or later as PdfRenderer class is added in API21. There is not compat library for PdfRenderer as of now.

Comment: Thanks. Actually there is a way to load a Vector via HTTP REQUEST. Soon I will post and example. I am thinking of to try to make a LOCAL HTTP REQUEST (IDK if this is possible) to be able to load the XML.

Or use Unity or other tool to develop a crossover-platform that support vectors. do you know any tool that suppor it?

Comment: Sorry, I have not explored this and don't know either. Please share the post once you have an example ready.